# DREAMFACTORY : Create User with Suspended State and Activate them with custom URL

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, email, resteasy

First i will explain what i need in Dreamfactory. After that i will explain the problem which i am facing.

I want to create a user registration form my back end is Dreamfactory and front end is Angular,

My open Registration options is enabled in Dreamfactory, Initially when registering a user with the URL "https://.cloud.dreamfactory.com:443/rest/user/register" The user's Conformation column and Active Column should be set to FALSE. After the Success Registration i need to send a E-Mail with my custom URL to the mail ID (NOTE : i like to have the activation code in URL itself ).

The user should redirect to my website after clicking the URL in mail (NOT TO DREAM FACTORY WEBSITE). from there i should retrieve the activation code from the URL and generate a POST request from angular to make the Active Column and Conformation column to SET TRUE.

Now i will explain the problem i am facing.

I created the POST request to register user with URL 
"https://APP-NAME.cloud.dreamfactory.com:443/rest/user/register"

```
{
'display_name' : NAME,
'email' : EMAIL,
'first_name' : FIRST NAME,
'last_name' : LAST NAME,
'new_password' : PASSWORD,
'is_active' : false,
'confirmed' : false 
}
```

but "is_active" and "confirmed" column is not setting to false. its still TRUE in DSP admin panel. I don't know why.

After this

It will be helpful for me if anyone explain how to generate a activation code and pass it through URL and receive in Angular.. After that How to post request to DSP and make that particular user Active and Confirmed.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the API does not support setting the active flag during registration. However, if you're using the confirmation code for registration, then this effectively makes the user inactive until they have confirmed their code. If the user tries to login without having confirmed their code they will get an error indicating they have not yet confirmed.